# .jar not running when passed valid file in args

Tags: java, batch-file, input, jar

I am building an application that takes input through an XML file and executes a number of operations based on it. I know the application works, because I can supply a file for an XML directly in code and it will run as it should.

The problem arises when I try to pass the path to an XML file in through the commandline args of the packaged .jar.

My main looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LogWriter.openWriter();

    LogWriter.log("Main start.");
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    LogWriter.log("Controller created.");

    List<Parameters> parameters = new ArrayList<Parameters>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        LogWriter.log("Got arg: " + args[i]);
        File file = new File(args[i]);
        LogWriter.log("Parameter file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (file.exists()) {
            LogWriter.log("File exists. Getting parameters.");
            Parameters para = controller.getParameters(file);
            LogWriter.log("Attempting to add parameters.");
            parameters.add(para);
            LogWriter.log("Added parameters.");
        } else {
            LogWriter.log("File is not valid.");
        }
    }
}
```

The script I use to run it looks like this:

```
java -jar PDFRedacter.jar C:\Users\je\Downloads\XMLConfig.xml
```

What is really strange about is, is that it only fails when I give it a valid file. If I supply an invalid file, it runs, and logs that the file is invalid, and as mentioned it also runs if I input a valid file directly in the code.

However, with a valid path written in the batch, not even the first 'Main start' is logged, so the code does not run at all. Is this perhaps some access problem?

EDIT: The logger is not my issue, it works as intended both with and without a valid file. Example of 'Invalid file' log:

> Main start.
>   Controller created.
>   Got arg: C:\Users\je\Downloads\XMLConfig
>   Parameter file: C:\Users\je\Downloads\XMLConfig
>   File is not valid.

To clarify, the issue is not actually reading a file. The issue is, that when I supply a valid file through the batch script, it seems like my code doesn't run at all.

FINAL EDIT:
It turns out the problem was simply with the packaging of my .jar, lacking a dependecy. As someone else suggested, my logger was only flushing at the very end of excecution, and that's why it didn't write anything. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: can you supply the output of your example call? What does an "invalid" file call look like?

Comment: It shouldn't be an access problem because at first the parameter is just a string. I'd suspect that your problem is `LogWriter` not being able to actually write the log to the console. Did you try with a simple `System.out.println("Main start.")`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). My bet (OK guess) is that the actual problem is in code not shown, like the `Controller`.

Comment: From your code `LogWriter.log("Got arg: " + args[i]);` should include the extenson `.xml` what your `invalid file log` sample obviously doesn't. So it seems the extension wasn't supplied.

Comment: That was intentional, to show the log for an invalid file.

Comment: What exactly is `LogWriter`? Is it your own class? And does it flush all output immediately after every call? It could be that the program is running but the output doesn't get flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas suspected, there must be another reason for the program to fail, because your function should work. If you reduce it to detecting if a file exists and once you made shure it works, add the parameter list, controller and logger one after another you may find the reason for the failure.´

Here is the example I tested - and it works perfectly for all existing files or directories.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Got arg: " + args[i]);
        File file = new File(args[i]);
        System.out.println("Parameter file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File exists. Getting parameters.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File is not valid.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it you fixed the problem - what was it?